# react router Link |{" "}

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, router

i wonder what this |{" "} could mean, when placed between two React Router links, as you see below

```
<Link to="/invoices">Invoices</Link> |{" "}
<Link to="/expenses">Expenses</Link>
```

thanks for the help !

The code is from the React Router documentetion, in the tutorial section.

Comment: Usually prettier the code formatter does that. You can remove it?

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is used to interpolate JavaScript inside your JSX.

Using `{" "}` is used to insert a space inside your JSX while avoiding any side effects. Using this to insert a space does not insert any HTML tag in your code.

---

The `{" "}` is an empty space after the `|`. No extra meaning. Maybe the developer visually separates the two links with `|` and added space around this.